# What is a good way attach the wire to the metal arm?

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

[image]

Both of these are IK, but I want to rig it so that the wires are dangling off of the Arm. I don't know how to accomplish that.

Comment: did you try hooks? cloth? GN?

Comment: Hook it to a vertex on the arm?